# Knockout computed items of observable array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have the following ViewModel:

```
var myViewModel = {
  categories: ko.observableArray([
    { name: ko.observable('Fruit'), 
      items: ko.observableArray([ 
        ko.observable('Apple'),
        ko.observable('Orange'), 
        ko.observable('Banana'), 
      ]),
    },
  ]),
};
```

I want to add a computed value for each item of this array:

```
$.each(myViewModel.categories(), function(index, cat){
  cat.num = ko.computed(function(){
    return cat.items().length;
  }, cat);
});
```

This is my HTML:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: { data: categories, as: 'category' }">
    <li>
        <ul data-bind="foreach: { data: items, as: 'item' }">
            <li>
                <span data-bind="text: category.name"></span>:
                <span data-bind="text: item"></span>
            </li> 
        </ul>
      <span data-bind="text: category.num"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And it works just great! Here is the result:

```
Fruit: Apple
Fruit: Orange
Fruit: Banana
3
```

But now let's say my data has changed and I need to reflect those changes:

```
myViewModel.categories([
  {
    name: "Fruit",
    items: ["Apple", "Banana"],
  },
  {
    name: "Veg",
    items: ["Potato", "Carridge"],
  }
]);
```

And it doesn't work - I don't see `num` at the end of each list. Could you please help me to fix this? Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/Rainfall/pen/ygvLPe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it does not work, because you are replacing the entire content of the `observableArray`. This code of yours:

```
$.each(myViewModel.categories(), function(index, cat){
    cat.num = ko.computed(function(){
        return cat.items().length;
    }, cat);
});
```

adds the `num` property to the items that exist in the array at the time of the call. By giving a new backing array to your `observableArray` by doing this:

```
myViewModel.categories([
  {
    name: "Fruit",
    items: ["Apple", "Banana"],
  },
  {
    name: "Veg",
    items: ["Potato", "Carridge"],
  }
])
```

you, of course, lose the old array and thus the computed observables which are defined *on the items* and not the observable array. Knockout of course has no way to know how and whether it should add the computed property to every item in the new array.

Solution:

You can either do the same property addition when you replace the backing array of your `observableArray` like this:

```
myViewModel.categories([
  {
    name: "Fruit",
    items: ["Apple", "Banana"],
  },
  {
    name: "Veg",
    items: ["Potato", "Carridge"],
  }
]);
$.each(myViewModel.categories(), function(index, cat){
    cat.num = ko.computed(function(){
        return cat.items().length;
    }, cat);
});
```

or better yet, you could instantiate the objects in the array with the property already defined. Note: you don't have to write the function over and over again for each item, you could, for instance, define a constructor for the array items:

```
function Category(name, items) {
  var self = this;

  this.name = name;
  this.items = ko.observableArray(items);
  this.num = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.items().length;
  });
};
```

and then, this is how you create a new one:

```
var newItem = new Category('Category 1', [ 'Apple', 'Banana']);
```

and insert it into the observable array:

```
myViewModel.categories.push(newItem);
```

this adds one item and keeps the existing ones, or, as you did, you could supply a whole new array as so:

```
myViewModel.categories([
  new Category('Fruit', ['Apple', 'Banana' ]),
  new Category('Veg', ['Potato', 'Carridge' ])
]);
```

Comment: What do you exactly expect to work differently and how? I see the numbers in your CodePen.

Comment: Sorry, I've changed my comment. I forgot to apply bindings. Your asnwer is awesome!